# Bootstrap dropdown not opening due to some issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap dropdown but its not opening. The code for the dropdown is as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <div class="checkbox" style="margin: 0;">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="all"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedAll"
                   (change)="selectAll($event);"/>
        </label>
    </div>
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unstarred</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have included all the necesary file and they are available.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy No error, its just not opening, changed title

Comment: Did you add Jquery library?

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru yes, its added

Comment: this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ej6eekf/) uses bootstrap 4 4.0 b3 and js bundle + jquery 3.2.1 and it works. You either added a wrong version or didn't add something

Answer (score 1):

Based on [bootstrap dropdown demos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns)
You should put your menu in a container has class `dropdown` as it show in this example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```